# Accepting cookies with Emacs URL package

Tags: url, cookies, emacs, lisp

I'm sending a POST request, it goes through fine but when I receive a cookie back it always gets rejected.

I've tried adding the url that sends me a cookie to the **url-cookie-trusted-urls** but they still get rejected.

Any idea why this might be?

There's really not much else to say I think... I'll be glad to answer any questions you might have.

Comment: Perhaps try accepting all cookies and then evaluate the url you've added to url-cookie-trusted-urls. (setq url-cookie-trusted-urls '(".*"))